# PHP replace smiley by img tag

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace smileycodes by a img tag.

I want to replace this:

```
:blush:
```

by:

```
<img src='images/blush.png' />
```

"blush" is a variabele, so it can be any smiley.

I have to replace everything between the colons. I am not familiar with regex.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple replacements you could use str_replace with arrays instead of strings to search for, having an array for smiley-codes to be replaced by values of the second array. But you need to configure all values in arrays what is kind of static.

Another solution was to loop over possible smiley-codes and do a str_replace for each of it:

```
$possibleCodes = array('blush', 'smiley2', 'smiley3');
foreach($possibleCodes as $code) {
  str_replace(':'.$code.':', "<img src='images/".$code.".png'", $yourString);
}
```

This requires to have the image name same as the smiley-code.

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex if you aren't familiar with it? It is very simple and easy to do without regex.

```
str_replace(":blush:", "<img src='images/blush.png' />", $myString);
```

Comment: Thank you, but "blush" is a variabele. I don't want to do this for every smiley. So I want to replace everything between the collons.

Comment: @Simon911 use a switch statement determining what type of emoticon it is, then use the above code and change `:blush:` to whatever the case is.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: a switch is pretty ugly if you have like 50 or more smileys. Better use arrays having the values for code and replacement image name or use a loop if both are same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` like as

```
preg_replace('~(:blush:)~','<img src="images/blush.png" />',$your_string);
```

**Edited**

If you had an array of string to replace then you can simply use `str_replace` like as

```
$find_array = array('blush', 'smiley2', 'smiley3');
$replace_array = ['<img src="images/blush.png" />','<img src="images/smiley2.png" />','<img src="images/smiley3.png" />']

str_replace($find_array,$replace_array,$your_string);
```

Comment: This will replace all values within double points by the image tag - even it's not a valid code for a smiley. Also every smiley code is replaced by the blush.png which is probably wrong.